# convert decimal number to n number

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def convert(n, base):
    T = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    q, r = divmod(n, base)
    if q == 0:
        return T[r]
    else:
        return convert(q, base) + T[r]


print convert(233, 2)
print convert(233, 8)
print convert(233, 16)
```

This is my school assignment. I googled convert decimal number to n number, but i cant understand this code. To be exact, this code process all.
Why did the developer used a recursive function?

I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: I don't know how that function works......

Comment: for example, I don't know why I'm typing 233 and 2 and I'm getting a binary number.

Comment: A recursive function is simply a function that calls itself. i.e. At line 7, in the `convert()` function, it calls `convert()` again.

Comment: I can understand recursive function, but I dont understand process of converting decimal number to n number .. TㅅT

Comment: Maybe it'll help if you list down (write on a piece of paper)each call. For e.g. first call: `convert(233, 2)`, followed by a recursive call: `convert(166, 2)`, so on and so forth. Up till q = 0, then work your way back up.

Comment: Oh thx !!!!!!! i understand everything!